# Enter key pressed inside a lightning input

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a `lightning:input` and when the focus is on it and you type the enter stroke: **it refreshes the page**.

I tried to prevent it by implementing the `onchange`: avoid the event to be fire <s>but the callback is never launched</s>.

Component.cmp:

```
<lightning:input
  type="email"
  onchange="{! c.callbackNeverCalled }"
/>
```

Controller.js:

```
callbackNeverCalled: function(component, event, helper) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Does not prevent from refreshing/redirecting the page & also 'deprecated'.

  event.getSource().getParams(); 
  // Is an empty object but the good way to do (cf. documentation)
}
```

Comment: Ok i checked the documentation of the lightning input and there is no onkeyup event. If you can add javascript to your page. Here's a [solution](http://webcheatsheet.com/javascript/disable_enter_key.php) I found.

Comment: My callback for the `onchange` event is now working. But there are still two issues: `event.preventDefault()` do not prevent from refreshing/redirecting the page and I can access the keyup by doing `event.getSource().getElement().KEYUP` (this will be deprecated, displayed at usage for `event.getSource().getParams()` but this does not return anything other than an empty object at the moment).

Comment: `event.KEYUP` give us this message: `Avoid relying on the native event attribute KEYUP as it is only included for backwards-compatibility. It will eventually be deprecated. Use the aura event API (e.g., getSource(), getParams(), etc) instead.`

Comment: Still not fixed..

Comment: @SimonPlacentino Are you putting your lightning:input in a form? This is typically not how you'd write a component/app.

Comment: @sfdcfox Not in a form but this is fixed and I can not remember how

Comment: How you prevent default event? @SimonPlacentino

Answer (score 19):

Thanks to SFDCFOX and PatMcClellan__c.
Workaround is:

```
<span onkeypress="{!c.keyCheck}" class="slds-size--11-of-12">
    <lightning:input aura:id="body" label="" name="Body" placeholder="Enter message..." value="{!v.Message.Body__c}" />
</span>

keyCheck : function(component, event, helper){
    if (event.which == 13){
        helper.onSend(component, event);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In LWC this works as

```
<span onkeypress={keycheck}>
    <lightning-input label="input1" data-fieldapiname="Name">
    </lightning-input>
</span>

 keycheck(component, event, helper){
    if (component.which == 13){
        // call the js method i.e. this.handlerfilter();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the oncommit event of the lightning-input component. No need to use a wrapper span. It can be found in the documentation in the lightning component library.

Comment: `commit` fires when you press enter _or_ when the input loses focus.  In a `type="search"` input, it also fires when the user clicks the "x" to clear the search field.  It does not include any params to tell you which occurred, so if you only want to take action when "enter" is pressed, it is not sufficient.

Comment: @jasonClark agreed.