# Why am I not seeing onkeydown when i inspect?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura

I am using input with an event onKeydown. But when inspect it is not showing onKeydown(It should show).

```
<input type="number"  onkeydown= "return event.keyCode == 190 ? false : true"     class="slds-input" />
```

When I inspect I am seeing this
[image: This is what I am seeing when I inspect input]

Please help me why am I not able to see

Comment: Behavior of HTML input element cannot be guaranteed when you are inside Aura framework. Obviously, the problem is caused by way Aura parses the code. If your concern is that `lightning:input` doesn't support key press events, then use the approach mentioned here: [Enter key pressed inside a lightning input](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155635/enter-key-pressed-inside-a-lightning-input)